# Iphone 6S+ WIFI Connectivity Issues

Tags: network, modem, iphone, safari

My Iphone 6s+ has been working fine on my rogers ignite wifi up until a week ago.. now I have been experiencing some odd issues.

Can't connect to certain sites - I can connect to google but I cannot connect to reddit/global news.

Can't connect to certain apps- I can connect to google home/whatsapp/youtube but no games

can't access modem from my Iphone6s+ browser

Safari says "cannot connect to server" if I try to go on reddit and if I try to access the modem from the safari browser, I get the following message: "cannot connect to internet".

I can't access the apple servers (to download from the app store).

I've tried:

restarting phone

clearing website and cache

resetting all network settings

restoring iphone (twice)

updating to newest OS

rebooting modem

resetting modem back to factory settings

The wifi works on all other devices (iphone 8/10/tvs/laptops) for downloading/reddit/mobile games.

I can use my iphone 6s+ mobile data/a different devices hotspot, to connect to reddit/app store on my 6s+ but it just won't work when I'm connected to the WIFI.

Does anyone have any ideas? This seems absurd... I've called my ISP and they said everything looks fine..

Sometimes, when I try accessing yahoo.ca from my iphone 6s+, it shows me a screen that says "This device is paused".. I've gone into the modem and it doesn't show this device is paused or blocked

Comment: I have an iPhone SE (6S in a 5 case) and I use Rogers. (1) disconnect and forget the Wireless Connection. Does Cellular connection work fine?   (2) Consider trying a different router off the Rogers Modem.  (3) I turned off Rogers wireless and set up my own wireless router.

Comment: Yes the cellular connection works fine, I might try disconnecting the Ignite pods. Does this sound like the wifi antenna is broken?

Comment: That is a distinct possibility since you did a fresh IOS install. You might consider calling Apple Support about this.